# reload the whole page after inserting a record in xcrud

Tags: php

I need to reload the xcrud listing view after adding a record via insert. Can anyone help how can i do this. As currently xcrud loads the page via ajax after inserting a record but i need to reload the whole page entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a function in functions.php in xcrud library.

```
function reloadPage($primary, $xcrud)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "location.reload();";
echo "</script>";
}
```

and then call it in your respective controller as `$xcrud->after_insert('reloadPage');`

Comment: No prob :) @IrshadAliJan